# Pandas magic with ugly CSV format

Tags: python, pandas, csv, string-formatting

An ancient atomic simulation software is producing really ugly CSV file, which I want to import to pandas dataframe. The format looks like this:

```
ITEM: TIMESTEP
0
ITEM: NUMBER OF ATOMS
491
ITEM: BOX BOUNDS pp pp pp
0.0000000000000000e+00 2.8000000000000000e+01
0.0000000000000000e+00 2.8000000000000000e+01
0.0000000000000000e+00 2.8000000000000000e+01
ITEM: ATOMS id type xs ys zs
1 1 0 0 0.142857
2 1 0.0714286 0.0714286 0.142857
3 1 0.0714286 0 0.214286
4 1 0 0.0714286 0.214286
...
491 1 2 2.3 0.4
ITEM: TIMESTEP
0
ITEM: NUMBER OF ATOMS
491
ITEM: BOX BOUNDS pp pp pp
0.0000000000000000e+00 2.8000000000000000e+01
0.0000000000000000e+00 2.8000000000000000e+01
0.0000000000000000e+00 2.8000000000000000e+01
ITEM: ATOMS id type xs ys zs
1 1 0 0 0.142857
2 1 0.0714286 0.0714286 0.142857
3 1 0.0714286 0 0.214286
4 1 0 0.0714286 0.214286
...
491 215 0.4 12.4 2.4
...
...
ITEM: TIMESTEP
1002
...
```

Basically it is a repeating header with the information of the iteration number. To me it seems that the easiest way to turn this into pandas would be df with the variables ['id', 'type', 'xs', 'ys', 'zs'] and add to it a new column "TIMESTEP", so it would be a nice 2D df. Alternatively could be a multi-index array Timestep 1 -> internal_df['id', 'type', 'xs', 'ys', 'zs']

The information lines (1-9) can be deleted.

The end result would ideally look like this:

```
    Index   a   b           c           d           TIMESTEP
    1       1   0           0           0.142857    0
    2       1   0.0714286   0.0714286   0.142857    0
    3       1   0.0714286   0           0.214286    0
    4       1   0           0.0714286   0.214286    0
    5       1   0.142857    0           0.142857    0
    ...
    474     1   0.78636     0.788005    0.425791    100002
```

Would you suggest a string-formatting script (example would be appreciated), or maybe Pandas read_csv with a smart set of settings could do it out of the box?

EDITED: Added true INFORMATION bit of the header, which is to be discarded (bit from "Number of Entries" to "Variables" line)

Comment: How should look like your _nice 2D df_ ? Can you add it to your question, please ?

Comment: Why 1002 is on the same line as TIMESTEP?

Comment: That's not a CSV. `CSV` specifically means `Comma Separated Values` but this looks like a multi-page report saved as a text file.

Comment: Assuming you don't need any data outside the tables you could try `read_table` or maybe even `read_csv` and discard "bad" rows, eg those with too many NaNs, whose first value isn't a number etc. If the number of headers and rows is fixed, you could pass a lambda to `skip_rows` that rejects rows by index.

Comment: It may be better to read and parse in your code though, and handle each section possible line type differently.

Comment: Panagiotis, the delimiter can easily be changed to ' ' in pandas, but the main issue is the repeating header with changing TIMESTEP, cheers.

Comment: That's not a CSV by any definition. The problem isn't TIMESTEP, it's that anything outside the tables isn't a table and can't be handled that way. Even if there was a single section with only a single `TIMESTEP` in the first line, you still wouldn't be able to use `read_csv` and get `TIMESTEP` in there

Comment: Yeap the data format is indeed annoying, hence the question. A hack would be if the machine saved each timestamp in a separate CSV, then the initial header can be ignored and what follows is just pure table of numbers. I basically deleted the irrelevant lines in Sublime, but that is not too safe as it loses information on the TIMESTEP (of course they are in sequence, but I want to automate this).

Comment: It looks like a mix between linebased records and space separated values. It would probably be relatively trivial to convert using awk and a 2d array. Update an index everytime you see `TIMESTEP`.  Then process lines that match pattern for actual data (`1 a1 b1..` ). At the end print out the array.  You can do the same thing using Python of course.

Comment: Assuming the output would be something [like this](https://pastebin.com/i2bPV9Y8) for the illustrated example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas), here is one way on how you can approach that (*to give you just the general logic*).

```
#pip install pandas
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
​
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s), sep="/", header=None)
​
m1 = df[0].str.contains("TIMESTEP")
m2 = df[0].str.contains("Information").fillna(False)
m3 = df[0].str.contains("ITEM|Variables|\+", regex=True).fillna(False)
​
conds, vals = [m1|m1.shift(1).fillna(False), m2|m3], ["DATA", "TO_SKIP"]
​
out = (
        df
          .assign(flag= pd.Series(np.select(conds, vals, None)).bfill().ffill())
          .pivot(columns="flag", values=0)
          .loc[:, "DATA"].dropna()
          .str.split(expand=True)
          .assign(col= lambda x: x[0].shift(-1).where(x[1].str.contains("TIMESTEP")).ffill())
          .set_axis(["Index", "a", "b", "c", "d", "TIMESTEP"], axis=1)
          .dropna(how="any")
          .reset_index(drop=True)
        )
​
```

Output :

```
print(out)

  Index    a          b          c         d TIMESTEP
0     1    1          0          0  0.142857        0
1     2    1  0.0714286  0.0714286  0.142857        0
2     3    1  0.0714286          0  0.214286        0
3     4    1          0  0.0714286  0.214286        0
4   491    1          2        2.3       0.4        0
5     1    1          0          0  0.142857        0
6     2    1  0.0714286  0.0714286  0.142857        0
7     3    1  0.0714286          0  0.214286        0
8     4    1          0  0.0714286  0.214286        0
9   491  215        0.4       12.4       2.4        0
```

*Disclaimer: This approach may not be efficient for large files.*

Comment: You should add it in to your question cauz' it's unreadable in the comments section.

Comment: This is great! I added more details on the "Information lines", but trying to use your solution to remove them :) Also, thanks, Timeless for suggestion of editing the OG question

Comment: We just need to add `|\+` in the third mask so we skip the lines containing the character +. I updated my answer and you're welcome, hope it helps ;)

Comment: I am learning loads... What does this regexy operator do? When I try running on my data, I get: `ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 8 elements, new values have 7 elements`. Which probably implies I have either the condition wrong or some mismatch of cols...

Comment: Seems like there is one extra column. Can you comment (`#`) the line where we call `set_index`, re-run the code  and share the output (_as a screenshot_) ?

Comment: Sorry you mean set_axis?

Comment: My bad, yeah `set_axis`, can you do that, please ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251549/discussion-between-gedas-sarpis-and-timeless).

Comment: @GedasSarpis, did you managed to make a screenshot ?

Comment: I wrote you in the chat as the discussion is expanding